# Using DSLCalendar in a Swift project

Tags: swift, calendar

I am trying to use DSLCalendar in my swift app.  So far I have managed to create a bridging header and imported the header:

```
#import "DSLCalendarView/DSLCalendarView.h"
```

I have added a UIView to the UIViewController and set it's custom class to DSLCalendarView.  I have assigned the delegate as well.  The editor successfully sees the class; however, the compiler complains about definitions.  Below is the code and below that is the error.  Any ideas?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, DSLCalendarViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var calendarView: DSLCalendarView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.calendarView.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func calendarView(calendarView: DSLCalendarView!, didSelectRange range: DSLCalendarRange!) {

    }
}
```

The error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DSLCalendarRange", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo16DSLCalendarRange in ViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_DSLCalendarView", referenced from:
  __TMaCSo15DSLCalendarView in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

A Swift version is now available:

https://github.com/ericcgu/DSLCalendarViewRedux